# JQuery - select val() only returns first value of dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a simple form summary script that returns all values entered in a form, and displays the values in a concise format in a dialog window.

The script works as intended for input fields, but for dropdowns it doesn't retrieve the currently selected value, but rather the first value in the dropdown.

Here's my HTML

```
<p><label> <b>*</b> Fruit </label>
  <select name="fruit">
    <option value="A">Apple</option>
    <option value="B">Orange</option>
    <option value="C">Pear</option>
  </select>
</p>
```

JQuery is as follows (abridged):

```
var summarizeForm = function (formContent) {
  var summary = formContent.clone();

  summary.find('select').each(function() {
    $(this).replaceWith($(this).val()); 
  });
  return summary;
}

$('#dialogSummary').children('.dialog_contents')
.replaceWith(summarizeForm(formContents));
```

In the above situation the summary return as 'A', regardless of what the user selects.

What can I do to make this work?

**Update**

In practice this should work, but JQuery cannot copy the dynamic state of a ('select'), as reported in this bug.

https://github.com/jquery/api.jquery.com/issues/90

The bug cannot be addressed due to performance reasons so I'll have to accomplish this another way.

> You can work around this limitation by separately copying the selectedIndex to your cloned select."

Comment: `replaceWith` change the element and you replace it with a value... I don't even know why it work with an input. I have an hard time to understand what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have alot of code if you just want to get the selected fruit value:

HTML:

```
<p><label> <b>*</b> Fruit </label>
  <select name="fruit" id="fruit">
    <option value="A">Apple</option>
    <option value="B">Orange</option>
    <option value="C">Pear</option>
  </select>
</p>

<div id="dialogsummary"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$("#fruit").change(function() {
    $("#dialogsummary").text("You selected: " + $(this).val());
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Laoujin/G574z/)

The clue is basically: `$(".fruit").val()` to get the selected value.
If you want instead the text (since you're building a summary): `$(".fruit").find(":selected").text();`

**Update**
If you want something 'generic' instead: (not tested)

```
var str = "";
summary.find("select").each(function() {
    str += "Value for " + $(this).prop('name') + " is " + $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: The excess code is to avoid hard coding it in for all elements, say there's a form with multiple dropdowns. So my understanding is I have to call .change() outside of the summarizeForm function?

Comment: The `.change()` will be called everytime the user selects an option in the dropdown. I used this because `summarizeForm` is never called in the code snippet you provided. Basically you'd need to use just `$(".fruit").val()` to get the selected value in the summarize.

Comment: I think I've figured it out. After a little debugging I've found that it's actually `.clone()` that resets the value to 'A'. Which is odd, but needless to say I'll keep this solution in mind for finding an alternate way, thanks for the help.