# Value of selected option is always the first option value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have the following jQuery code to display the selected option value and text in a separate div. The code is as follows:

```
<script>
$("#icddiagnosiscodes").change(function() {
var value = $( "#icddiagnosiscodes" ).val();//to get content of "value" attrib
var text = $( "#icddiagnosiscodes option:selected" ).text();//to get <option>Text</option> content
$("#icddiagcode").html("Diagnosis Code: " + value);
$("#icddiagdes").html("Diagnosis Description: " + text);
})
</script>
```

Html is:

```
<select  id="icddiagnosiscodes" name="icddiagnosiscodes" style="width:300px;height:40px;">
<option  selected="selected">Select ICD-10-CM Diagnosis Codes</option>
</select>
<div id ="icddiagcode"></div>
<span id ="icddiagdes"></span>
```

Values & text updated using Ajax request to DB.

But unfortunately the **value displayed on first select is always the first option value**. There is a similar issue posted in stackoverflow:

[JQuery - select val() only returns first value of dropdown](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698227/jquery-select-val-only-returns-first-value-of-dropdown)

with no solution, exceept that the OP has specified the following based on a jQuery bug report:

**You can work around this limitation by separately copying the selectedIndex to your cloned select."**

The bug report is at:
https://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/12479

As a newbie, I can't understand what is meant by:
**copying the selectedIndex to your cloned select**

How is that possible using Jquery ?? Help requested from experts.

**Update:**
It was an issue with me not providing value in ajax option update. I added a `value=''` and it is okay now.

```
$("select#icddiagnosiscodes").prepend("<option selected='selected' value=''>Select ICD-10-CM Diagnosis Codes</option>");
```

Comment: Can you share the relevant HTML for your issue?

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek Updated post to include html.

Comment: In your example your select only has one option. It also has no value attribute. Please update your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: It is an ajax updated select box.

Comment: That's fine. Simply add some option elements that your AJAX request would normally add. Also note that the bug you pointed to was both closed five years ago and marked as invalid.

Comment: Your jQuery code is working fine for me https://jsfiddle.net/fnhee8df/

Comment: @Spencer Wieczorek If we select option 2 and then option 1 it will work fine.

Comment: @j08691
Json values like
i cd_diagnosis_code A00 
icd_diagnosis_name Cholera

Comment: Please update your question's code with a [mcve]. Without it we cannot help you. And as Azim showed you, what you have so far works. Note what I said as well. Your example option has no value attribute .

Comment: I'm not seeing issues with this code, can you provide a runnable example reproducing the issue you are seeing?

Comment: I'm getting the itch that this is something to do with the default value on page load, or changing the value logically (such as the ajax changing the options) that isn't triggering the change event.

Comment: @Azim Wonder what is going wrong with my code.